# Customized date and time display in Jquery

Tags: jquery, date, time

I want to display system current time and date details in one table td.  The expected output format should be like this:

```
12 Jun 2014
12:35:23
```

Can anyone help me out to get this done by jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is the code I tried. 
var d = new Date();
                var day = d.getDate();
                var month = d.getMonth() + 1;                
                var time = d.getTime();
                var output = d.getFullYear() + ' ' +                    
                    (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day + '' +
                    (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + ' ' +
                    (('' + time).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + time;var day = d.getDate();

Displayed format is coming like this: 2014 0307 1404379598887

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code to it. Don't put code into a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var date=new Date();
 var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

 var formatedDate= (date.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + '  ' +      date.getFullYear());
 alert(formatedDate);

  //or  with time:-
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
    var formatedDatewithTime = (date.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[date.getMonth()] + '  ' + date.getFullYear()) +' '+hour+':'+min+':'+secs;
    alert(formatedDatewithTime)

   });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jHqU/3/)

Comment: Hi Mohit, thanks a lot.  It is working. Great. But how can i get the time display as expected format of "12:35:23". And also if the date digit count is single that should have prefix "0" like date 3 should be 03.

Comment: @user3667940 for add zero check this http://jsfiddle.net/5jHqU/4/ and please accept as answer if it helps thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // July 3rd 2014, 11:25:51 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Thursday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jul 3rd 14
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2014 escaped 2014
moment().format();                          // 2014-07-03T11:25:51+02:00
```